# Как автоматически изменить размер у wx.CheckListBox в wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

Текст(label) каждого checkbox у виджета wx.Checklistbox может быть произвольным.

Нужно автоматически менять размер wx.Checklistbox, если текст(label) checkbox выходит за рамку виджета wx.CheckListbox.

**Вопрос:** как установить соответствие между длинной строки(label) checkbox и виджетом wx.Checklistbox?